# How can i convert not printable ascii characters to readable string for flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6, extended-ascii

I have problems with reading text from an external XML.
Flash doesn't seem to have problem with ascii characters from (32-127), but it isn't able to show extended characters (128 - 255).
In that XML i have for example „ (DEC: 132) and “ (DEC:147).
In the XML those characters are not visible, but still there. Flash isn't able to show them. My approach was to get each charCode and convert it to string, but that does only work for printable characters.

```
var textToConvert:String = xml.parameters.text[1].value;
            trace("LENGTH = "+textToConvert.length);
            var test:String="";
            for(var i:int=1;i<textToConvert.length;i++){
                trace(textToConvert.charCodeAt(i));
                //OCT
                trace(textToConvert.charCodeAt(i).toString(8));
                //HEX
                trace(textToConvert.charCodeAt(i).toString(16));
                //HEX
                test += textToConvert.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
                trace("SYMBOL : " +String.fromCharCode(textToConvert.charCodeAt(i)))
            }
            trace("TEST: "+test);
```

Result:

> 76
>
> 114
>
> 4c
>
> SYMBOL : L
>
> 132
>
> 204
>
> 84
>
> SYMBOL : (Not Visible)

The next thing i was doing, is to attach an escape sequence to each char "\x" to the HEX-Value and then convert it to String, but that doesn't work either:

```
s = "\x93\x93\x84\x93\x84";

            ba.writeMultiByte(s,"ASCII");
            trace(s);
```

This was my first approach (not working):

```
var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
byteArray.writeMultiByte(textToConvert,"iso-8859-1");
trace("HIER: "+byteArray.readUTFBytes(byteArray.bytesAvailable));
```

What would be an universal apporach to solve this problem?

This is the xml, it has hidden ascii characters (quotes). I want to parse the values of the nodes including those characters:

[XML-DL](http://we.tl/s7vqTXBtsf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally AS3 strings are encoded as 16-bit Unicode. They support your characters. It has also decoded it correctly as it has read the correct char code.

Does the font used for output have a glyph capable of rendering it? This applies even to the AS3 console. Your char isn't "empty", it just can't draw it. If you changed your trace to include quotes either side of the character you would see it writes the empty space still.

If you dump it to a TextField instead using a font you know has the correct support then it should work as expected.

If this doesn't meet your needs then you will need to do some kind of conversion. There is no generally accepted library to do this, as it is dependent on your needs. What should be done with single chars that typically need multiple to represent them? ø is normally translated to 'oe' but that may not be suitable in a fixed length string. There isn't an equiv for a most Hebrew, Cyrillic, Arabic etc letters. What rules do you want to apply to those? You need to decide what you need then do a conversion that matches those requirements (or pick a library that meets it).

Comment: All I want is to dump that nodevalue into a textfield. I don't know what conversion I have to do. The textfield should display all characters. For example String.fromCharCode(132), should display a „ but it doesn't. Fonts are embedded, I use Verdana and Times New Roman for my tests. Another example: With the string "Hello: „„„ END" I get "Hello: END" in the textfield. The string in the xml looks similiar, the quotation marks are somehow encoded (the are there, but not visible).

Comment: 132 is a control in [Latin 1 suppliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_%28Unicode_block%29), it won't display, it's not meant to. The „ character is 8222 (201E). I also don't see this character anywhere in your uploaded XML file when viewed as UTF8. I'm not sure this is a Flash problem.

Comment: If you use the arrow-keys in value node you'll see that the cursor doesn't move for quite a bit. These are the characters encoded in the XML. However, if I type it directly in the XML (ALT+132) and run the .fla file I get the char code 8222 which is latin1 encoded, and properly displayed in the textfield. The question now would be, how can I convert extended ascii characters to latin1?
byteArray.writeMultiByte(textToConvert,"iso-8859-1");
 doesn't seem to work.

Comment: As explained, there is no complete translation of UTF8 to ASCII, there are only approximations which different in effectiveness depending on your in and out needs. However I don't think this matters in this case. If the content isn't correctly representing what you expect BEFORE it gets into Flash, then surely that's the part you should be fixing? Your XML is marked as UTF8, and when decoding as such I get the same content that Flash is (correctly) reading.